# Using Google Apps Scripts to generate shareable links of new files

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting

I recently discovered this Google Apps Scripts feature and am wondering if my issue can be addressed by using that.

Let's say I have a machine generating new files (screenshots or videos taken from a capture card) that are being saved in a folder that is sync'd to my Google Drive. What I would like to do is somehow automatically generate a shareable link for each NEW file that gets added and send it to an email address (may or may not be a Gmail address).

Is this something that I can use Google Apps Scripts for? I tried looking into batch files first but I can't generate the shareable link automatically (or couldn't figure out how).

I don't have any code yet, just looking at potential approaches.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes almost everything is possible in GAS. However, you are likely to find better answers when you post some code that you have tried yourself before asking the answer here.

However, if the machine automatically saves the files in a folder in google drive you can scan that folder with a script and find the links. Attach a trigger to it with a, for example, 5 minute interval and write those links on a spreadsheet.

an example:

```
function links(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('put google folder id here');
var files = folder.getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var vals = file.getUrl();
   sheet.getRange(your range you want to paste the link).setValues(vals);
 }
}
```

This will find the links of all the files in the folder and paste that onto a google spreadsheet where the code is linked to. 
Use that spreadsheet as a database and send an email by using that database.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, the main problem is that I have never worked with GAS before so I didn't even know where to start but I hear you on the code piece. 
Again, really appreciate your response and suggestion!